# How to disable a dojo enhanced grid?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a grid which I want to disable based on some conditions. I am using the following syntax to disable it:

```
dojo.byId('gridId').disabled = true;
```

The above syntax disables the grid but the cellClick event still occurs.
Is there any method by which can disable the Selector plugin or is my approach incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there's a difference between the DOM node of the grid and the grid widget. When using `dojo.byId()`, you're actually referring to the DOM node, by disabling the DOM node you will probably disable all normal DOM events.

However, the widget itself acts on its own and when changing the widget you should be using `dijit.byId()`. I just looked at the [API documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid) of the `EnhancedGrid`, but as far as I can see it doesn't support disabling the grid.

Comment: dojo.byId() disables the grid but not the selector plugins.I want to disable the selector plugin along with the widget.Is it possible?